# What is an acceptable gap between glass shower door panels?

Tags: plumbing, shower

In our new shower, the gap between the fixed glass panel and glass door is 7/16". The installer is telling us that this is acceptable, but that gap allows water to splash through.
He obviously does not want to redo the glass.
Is there an industry standard? What is acceptable?

Comment: What's the gap on the hinge side?

Comment: 1/4" to the wall on the hinge side.

Comment: I'm not sure how a smaller gap would prevent splashing. Either the design is bad or you need to aim your shower head more carefully.

Comment: Is the fixed glass mounted to the wall on the shower head end of the tub? Is the sliding glass on the inside or the outside?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a bit bigger a gap than normal.

If you decide to live with it, there are sweeps and L shapes you can attach. One manufacturer is CR Lawrence: [CRL shower door wipes and seals](https://www.crlaurence.com/crlapps/showline/default.aspx?GroupID=60592&History=39326:26923&pom=0)

In particular, the one I'd look at is the "CRL Translucent Vinyl Edge 'T' Wipe". Alternately, the PCC10/PCC12 might work for you.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

So use a soft silicone tube to fill the gap - just remember to stick it to one side only...

Comment: The gap is the opening between the moving glass and the stationary glass so it can't be sealed. Sorry if I didn't describe it well.

Comment: Silicone can be used to make the gap smaller.  A piece of tape will keep it sticking to the door/moving section.